# How to communicate between 2 vue-native apps

Tags: firebase, vue-native

I want to communicate between 2 vue-native apps. Like 1 app will order to turn on the light, the other one will take that order and implement it. As database, I am using firebase

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Firebase, this is rather easy to accomplish using Firebase's RTDB data events. Ironically a couple months ago I have made a library that simplifies this process based on Firebase.

Its called [Signalz](https://signalz.js.org/), install it using npm or yarn:

```sh
npm i signalz
// OR
yarn add signalz
```